# Print Nightmare Patch KB5004947 for Windows 10 LTSB and LTSC versions?

Tags: windows, windows-10, security, windows-update

recently Microsoft officially published patches to heal a severe vulnerability in the PrintSppoler Service called "PrintNightmare" in the media. These patches can be found here on the official Microsoft homepage:

https://msrc.microsoft.com/update-guide/vulnerability/CVE-2021-34527

However, none of the patches offered here works for the Windows 10 Enterprise LTSC versions 2016 (formerly LTSB) or 2019.

Sine LTSC 2016 is based on Windows 10 Build 1607, there is no downloadable content here.

But LTSC 2019 is based on Windows 10 Build 1809, and there is a patch available, however when I try to install this patch (in the correct flavor for 64 Bit systems) on an affected 2019 LTSC system, I get an error message "This update is not applocable to your computer".

Where can I find the patches for the Windows 10 Enterprise LTSC versions?

Comment: "Where can I find the patches for the Windows 10 Enterprise LTSC versions?" - They have not been released at this time.

Answer (score 1):

ZD Net just now (July 7, 2021):

[Microsoft PrintNightmare patch](https://www.zdnet.com/article/install-immediately-microsoft-delivers-emergency-patch-for-printnightmare-security-bug/?ftag=TRE-03-10aaa6b&bhid=23164040498209351948461508422926&mid=13427922&cid=716451735&eh=415d31378861548db4da201cb4d1617f0af8e93816573d09ab282988de5dc38b)

> Microsoft is offering patches for unsupported versions of Windows to
> plug the so-called PrintNightmare bugs
>
> The PrintNightmare bug is being tracked as CVE-2021-1675 and
> CVE-2021-34527. It's a critical bug in the Windows print spooler with
> exploit code in the public domain before Microsoft had a chance to
> release a patch for it. Admins were advised to disable the Print
> Spooler service until a patch was made available.

Patch now.

Tech News just posted the same thing (July 7, 2021). Follow up and if necessary ask Microsoft Support. But a patch is out now.

[More Print Patches](https://www.zdnet.com/article/get-updating-microsoft-delivers-printnightmare-patch-for-more-windows-versions/?ftag=TRE-03-10aaa6b&bhid=23164040498209351948461508422926&mid=13429167&cid=716451735&eh=415d31378861548db4da201cb4d1617f0af8e93816573d09ab282988de5dc38b)

> Microsoft has released patches for more versions of Windows affected
> by the PrintNightmare bug, but researchers claim the patches don't
> provide complete protection.
>
> Microsoft released out-of-band patches for Windows systems affected by
> two critical bugs being tracked as CVE-2021-1675 and CVE-2021-34527,
> and has advised admins to disable the print spooler service until
> patches are applied. One is a remote code execution flaw, while the
> second is a local privilege escalation bug.
>
> "Microsoft identified a security issue that affects all versions of
> Windows and have expedited a resolution for supported versions of
> Windows that will automatically be applied to most devices," it said
> in an update on Wednesday

Follow up from ZD Net August 10, 2021

[ZD Net Print Error fixed](https://www.zdnet.com/article/microsofts-august-2021-patch-tuesday-45-flaws-fixed-seven-critical-including-print-spooler-vulnerability/?ftag=TREc64629f&bhid=%7B%24external_id%7D&mid=%7B%24MESSAGE_ID%7D&cid=%7B%24contact_id%7D&eh=%7B%24CF_emailHash%7D)

> One of the most prominent patches released in the latest batch covers
> the Windows Print Spooler Remote Code Execution vulnerability, which
> has been a major topic of discussion since it was discovered in June.
> Microsoft also faced backlash from the security community for bungling
> the release of patches meant to address the issue.

@Erik - It seems by now this error will be fixed in your systems by updating to the August 10 Patch Tuesday updates out now.

Comment: Earlier in the day, there were particular versions of the OS that did not yet have patches. the lastest version of the CVE from MS do now show all versions supported: https://msrc.microsoft.com/update-guide/vulnerability/CVE-2021-34527

Comment: Today's patches should cover all / most older versions - so far as I have read in the patch articles.

Comment: That is correct, now. but 10 hours ago, when the question was asked, about 12 versions had no patch available including Server 2016. that's why I mention it. the Op wasn't looney.